# Print base path in html.tpl.php

Tags: theming, uri

Im trying to print the full path to my theme in my html.tpl.php file. In the following code the 2nd part prints correctly but the first part does nothing.

```
<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed my code wasnt working as I was expecting an absolute url but Ive now realized that when Drupal is in the route it just returns a /. So it is in fact working fine.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
base_path().drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME')
```

Other Examples of path

```
$GLOBALS['base_url'] => http://example.com/drupal
base_path() => /drupal/
request_uri() =>    /drupal/documentation?page=1
request_path() => documentation
current_path() => node/26419
```